# Android: Getting permission info description in different language

Tags: android, localization, permissions

I am able to display all permissions for a given application using PackageInfo.requestedPermission. For each PermissionInfo object I can retrieve a label and a description using PackageManager.getPermissionInfo() and then calling loadLabel() and loadDescription().

What I get are some strings in the currently selected language of the device.

I want to retrieve them **always** in English (or some other given language). Is this possible?

Comment: Have u solved this issue? I face localization description issue too!

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that is possible using the published APIs

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: "Not possible" is a legit answer to many questions, and I don't think it's worse than repeating the same comment twice.